# Easy way to import zurb foundation for sites into nuxt project?

Tags: vue.js, zurb-foundation, nuxt.js

How do I import zurb foundation for sites(eventually bootstrap) into my nuxtjs project.

Answer (score 0):

add the CSS resources to `nuxt.config.js` file as follows :

```
  export default {
      css: [ 
     '@/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',

     ]
}
```

or  try this :

```
link: [     
{rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'}
]
```

Comment: A CDN link is not recommended for different reasons (GDPR, availability, performance, ...). Also the question is about Foundation Sites which also has jQuery and its own JS file as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing foundation-sites to your project (it may ask you to also install a couple other things like what-input, etc.):

```
npm install foundation-sites
```

Then, if you're using the nuxt-cli project, under your `/assets` directory, include an `/scss` directory with an `app.scss` file from their documentation, which you can find [here under their Starter Project section](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sass.html#adjusting-css-output).

Replace `@import 'foundation';` with `@import '~foundation-sites/scss/foundation';` This is a Nuxt quirk.
Add an `@import 'global';` above that and then copy the `_global.scss` from `/node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/` into the same directory as your `app.scss` file.

Next you're going to want to hop into your `nuxt.config.js` file in your root and add this just after your `head: {},`:

```
css: [
{ lang: 'scss', src: '@/assets/scss/app.scss' },
```

]

and within `build: {}`, you'll want to tell webpack to load this stuff up, so include something like:

```
extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
  for (const rule of config.module.rules) {
    if (rule.use) {
      for (const use of rule.use) {
        if (use.loader === 'sass-loader') {
          use.options = use.options || {};
          use.options.includePaths = ['~/node_modules/foundation-sites/scss', '~/node_modules/motion-ui/src'];
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You should be good from there to hop into your page and component files now and start using it right away. If you have any issues with jquery, I actually loaded mine at the end of my `head: {}` in my `nuxt.config.js` file, like:

```
script: [
  {
    src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js',
    integrity: 'sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=',
    crossorigin: 'anonymous',
    body: true
  }
]
```

By adding `body: true` in there, you're telling the script to load in the body and not within the head, even though it's called within `head: {}`. You can additionally call this in on a page by page basis within your `module.exports` to avoid loading it where you don't need it.